# Extremizing an Integral which is the RHS of a Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the problem of finding a continuously twice-differentiable function $x(t)$ which extremizes the convergent improper integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x,s)\mathop{ds}
\end{equation}
given that
\begin{equation}
G\left(x(t),\frac{\mathop{dx}}{\mathop{dt}},\frac{\mathop{d^2x}}{\mathop{dt^2}}\right)=I.
\end{equation}
Letting $X(s)=x(s)+\epsilon\eta(s)$, for continuously twice-differentiable $\eta(s)$ such that $\eta(t)=\lim_{s\rightarrow -\infty}\eta(s)=0$,
\begin{align}
I(\epsilon)&=\int_{-\infty}^{t} f(X,s)\mathop{ds},\\
I'(\epsilon)&=\int_{-\infty}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial \epsilon}\mathop{ds},\\
I'(0)&=\int_{-\infty}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\eta(s)\mathop{ds},\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
I(\epsilon)&=G\left(X(t),\dot{X},\ddot{X}\right),\\
I'(\epsilon)&=\frac{\partial G}{\partial X}\eta_t+\frac{\partial G}{\partial \dot{X}}\dot{\eta}_t+\frac{\partial G}{\partial \ddot{X}}\ddot{\eta}_t,\\
I'(0)&=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\eta_t+\frac{\partial G}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{\eta}_t+\frac{\partial G}{\partial \ddot{x}}\ddot{\eta}_t,\\
&=\frac{\partial G}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{\eta}_t+\frac{\partial G}{\partial \ddot{x}}\ddot{\eta}_t,\\
&=0.
\end{align}
How can I proceed from here to derive an appropriate modification of the Euler-Lagrange equations for this case?

Comment: Your second equation is a constraint on $x$ while your first is the objective youa ctually want to minimize. You need to introduce a Lagrange multiplier then extremize the augemented cost function $L(x,\lambda) = I(x) + \lambda(G(x) - I(x))$